# Ultrasurf causing huge network latency

Tags: networking, proxy, administration, squid

We run a small network with a Squid proxy. Over the last few weeks, the network has been slowing down and completely stopping for no apparent reason. We discovered that it was due to some users running ultrasurf. We were able to block ultrasurf from connecting to its severs using something we found online (which we added to our squid.conf). Now although squid doesnt let ultrasurf connect, just leaving it on practically stops the network completely.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to troubleshoot. What happens when the network is slow? Is internal traffic slow? Is your Internet link maxed out? Are proxy servers overloaded? Is the router CPU maxed? Are internal LAN links dropping packets?